# Upload File while application in background : ASIHTTPRequest with Phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I am using the ASIFormDataRequest for uploading file on server.
I am using ASIHTTPRequest to achieve the functionality of upload in background.

It working fine. But When application going to background then it fail to upload the file.

I try a lot of test with my code, even sometime it works for background too.
When I am uploading file and application going to background and then application again active then it upload successfully.
I notice that (but not sure) if application going in background for time more than the request time out time then it fail to upload. *(I am not sure about it)*

```
NSString *filePath = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.107/~amitb/test/upload.php"];
NSData *imageData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath] autorelease];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.delegate = self;
[request setData:imageData withFileName:fileName andContentType:nil forKey:@"file"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Can anybody help me to upload file while application in background

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#background_downloads_ios states that you can use:

```
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

Comment: I just this line in my code .. Is my code uploading files in chunks or upload a complete file

Comment: It's uploading the complete file in one HTTP transaction.

Comment: can you suggest me is it fine or should I upload in chunks

Comment: It's fine for most cases - eg. facebook / twitter upload photos in the same way. I can't really comment though as I don't know what your requirements are; if you're uploading very big files on a slow or intermittent network connection chunking might help you, but it's a lot more work/code so I wouldn't do it unless you have a good reason (requirement) to do so.